When inserting scripts to innerHTML, scripts with DOMContentLoaded are not executed
I made a script that takes the text of a html file and inserts it into another html file; I did this so I don't need to update my header and sidebar on every page if I make a change. the script works to insert the html but some scripts from the file are not run once inserted into the main html.
function includeHTML() {
    let elements = document.querySelectorAll("[include-html]");

    for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { 
        const elem = elements[i];
        let file = elem.getAttribute("include-html");
        
        fetch(file).then(response => response.text()).then(data => {
            elem.innerHTML = data; // inject html
            
            let scripts = elem.querySelectorAll("script");
            for (let i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) { // find scripts
                let script = scripts[i];
                let newScript = document.createElement("script");

                let attrs = script.attributes;
                for (let i = 0; i < attrs.length; i++) { // copy attributes
                    attr = attrs[i];
                    newScript.setAttribute(attr.name, attr.value);
                };
                newScript.innerHTML = script.innerHTML // copy internal script
                script.replaceWith(newScript); // replace script
            };
        }); 
        elem.removeAttribute("include-html");
    };
};

includeHTML();

^ this is my script, after inserting to innerHTML it replaces the scripts, this make some work but not others
<html>
    <head>
        <script defer src="/include.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div include-html="/file.html"></div>
    </body>
</html>

^ and this is an example of how I would use it
if the script inserted uses DOMContentLoaded I guess it is inserted after it's already fired so it isn't executed, one solution I found is to fire DOMContentLoaded manually after a second but I feel like this could be dependent on the users computer/internet speed, and it would make any scripts elsewhere on the page run twice if they catch the first firing so surely this is not the best way of doing it
by the way I am hosting on neocities so I dont have any backend access, thank you in advance for any help

"one solution I found is to fire DOMContentLoaded manually after a second but I feel like this could be dependent on the users computer/internet speed" - no, it can't, not in this situation. The document that you are executing your above JS in, has already loaded. And the scripts from the "included" HTML all run in the context of that same document, so there is no way that DOMContentLoaded inside any of these scripts would fire on its own in this scenario, no matter how fast or slow they were actually loaded.

You'd have to be careful though, any DOMContentLoaded handlers that might have been in the scripts the page originally loaded already, would execute again, if you fired that event after loading your new "included" scripts.

As you've correctly identified:

if the script inserted uses DOMContentLoaded I guess it is inserted after it's already fired so it isn't executed,

That's right: the DOMContentLoaded event has already fired on the document and it won't fire again.
Fortunately, there is a (little-known) way around this:
The document has a property: readyState.
Initially, the value of document.readyState is loading.
Just before the DOMContentLoaded event fires on the document, the value of document.readyState is interactive.
Just before the load event fires on the window, the value of document.readyState is complete.
So, if you want to know if the DOMContentLoaded event has already fired, you can check for:
if ((document.readyState === 'interactive') || (document.readyState === 'complete')) {
  ... CODE HERE...
}


Further Reading:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState

